# My other folders and images won't work and link with the website

Tags: html, css, file, web, inspect-element

I have a folder with more folders and files in it. It looks like this:

```
Game Name 
  -Elements
    --Website
      ---Images
      ---Fonts
      ---Scripts
      ---Documents
    --Game
```

The index.html and webstyle.css files are in the websites folder and the image I'm using is in the images folder, of course. This is what the code for it looks like, it's in the CSS file:

```
body {
  background-image: url("/images/bg.jpg");
}
```

The thing is I tried checking the website to see if it worked but it didn't, I even checked to see if the image was there at all, it wasn't, and neither were any of the folders or files except for the HTML and CSS documents.

Comment: add your structure as picture

Comment: What is the URL of the page being viewed when you test this?

Comment: if it's on Linux then `images/bg.jpg` is not considered same thing as `Images/bg.jpg`

Comment: Since you started the URL with `/`, it is also relevant what folder your document root points to.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you have written the wrong folder name. You have written /images instead of /Images.

Code:

```
body {
  background-image: url("/Images/bg.jpg");
}
```